# Persisting Orion Events in a Different Database

Tags: fiware, fiware-cygnus

What would it take to persist the Orion events in a database other than MySQL, like PostgreSQL, using Cygnus?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to persists Orion context data in PostgreSQL (or any other backend not yet considered by Cygnus) you will have to create your own sink, let's say, `OrionPostgreSQLSink`.

Being said that... don't panic! It should be quite easy :) We at Cygnus team have written this [guidelines](https://fiware-cygnus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cygnus-ngsi/user_and_programmer_guide/adding_new_sink/index.html) regarding new sinks creation by external contributors. Basically, creating a new sink for Cygnus is as easy as exending `OrionSink` class and implementing the `persist()` method. In addition, most of the code from `OrionMySQLSink` could be re-used; most probably the most specific part will be the development of a `PostgreSQLBackend` convenience class.

**UPDATE:**

Some time has passed, and a sink for PostgreSQL is now available in Cygnus! Please check this [link](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/blob/master/doc/cygnus-ngsi/flume_extensions_catalogue/ngsi_postgresql_sink.md) for further details.